# URLs are being double encoded in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

I have a custom user password reset page, it works well, sending an email with a unique URL to reset the password such as:

```
https://website.org/reset-password?action=rp&key=chMOWDgCb8h7eFZZby1w&login=Test%20User
```

When I put the URL into the browser, I am directed to:

```
https://website.org/reset-password?action=rp&key=chMOWDgCb8h7eFZZby1w&login=Test%2520User
```

If I manually remove the `25` from `%2520` the URL works, but I cant figure out how to keep it from double encoding those characters.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the %20 is being encoded as a **literal** %20 and not a space.

Therefore when you're generating your link it should be:

```
your_function_to_generate_password_link('https://website.org/reset-your-password?action=rp&key=chMOWDgCb8h7eFZZby1w&login=Test User');
```

And not:

```
your_function_to_generate_password_link('https://website.org/reset-your-password?action=rp&key=chMOWDgCb8h7eFZZby1w&login=Test%20User');
```

I suspect you're currently doing something like this (or wordpress is encoding it):

```
htmlentities($yourpasslink);
```

And the link itself contains `%20` rather than a literal space:  .

If you were to run htmlentities twice this is what happens:

```
$test = " ";
$first_try = htmlentities($test); // outputs %20
echo $first_try; // outputs %20
echo htmlentities($first_try); // outputs %2520
```

`%25` is the entity code for `%` and as `2` and `0` don't need encoded, it results in: `%2520`.